# ArrayAdapter's add method adding twice

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have `IconicAdapter` extending `ArrayAdapter`:

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    IconicAdapter() {
            super(MyService.this, R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.text1, entries);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            return(row);
    }
}
```

When I am using **add** method, it is adding twice:

```
IconicAdapter ia=new IconicAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ia);
            ia.add("1000");
```

Any reason why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this.

```
IconicAdapter ia=new IconicAdapter();`
```

you are adding adapter to list, here you already the adapter.

```
 lv.setAdapter(ia);
```

then here what you wanted to  do .

```
    iv.add("1000"); here add something in listview not in adapter
```

Comment: No Cobra.. by doing ia.add("1000"); I am just adding one more item to the ListView..

Comment: I don't understand. There is no method such as "add(String str)" in ListView. How can this be an accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but it turns out it was a very stupid mistake on my part. Maybe this will help some people though. The problem was that I was adding the items twice, both in the `ArrayAdapter` and in the list with the items.

Basically, if you use the constructor:

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)`

or

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)`

then you should avoid keeping a reference to the `objects` list that you passed, because the adapter just keeps a reference to it without copying its values. If you need to know the value of these objects from somewhere else then either make a copy of them or simply use the `getCount()` and `getItem(int position)` methods to access them. You should definitely avoid trying to modify the array or the list that is referenced by the `ArrayAdapter`.

Hope this helps someone :D